# Выдает кракозябру в laravel

Tags: laravel

```
<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru');
echo $row->created_at->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');?>
```

Answer (score 1):

А если так

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.CP1251', 'rus_RUS.CP1251', 'Russian_Russia.1251');
```

Если не работает, значит нет поддержки.

https://github.com/LaravelRUS/localized-carbon

Поддерживает несколько языков

```
English (en)
Russian (ru)
Ukrainian (uk)
Dutch (nl)
Spanish (es)
Portuguese (pt)
```

Так же можно попробовать поменять в `/app/config/app.php` : `'locale' => 'en'`

Comment: Все равно кракозября

Comment: @das Написал ещё варианты